# Get Unique list of values from array inside hash perl

Tags: perl

I have a hash which contains a list of array and i have to get a unique list from that array . But when i am trying to id i am not getting any error or the unique list.

**NOTE : I don't want to use any module**.

Below is the sample structure of my hash which has the array :

```
'15445' => { 'str' => {
                        'TOKEN' => [
                           'HC',
                           'HC',
                           'HC',
                           'HC',
                           'HC',
                           'HC'
                            ]
                }
        }
```

How i am tying to get a unique list of values from the array `TOKEN`

```
foreach my $id (keys %$client) {
    my @unique_srp_id;
    @unique_srp_id = uniq($hash->{$id}->{str}->{TOKEN});
    print @unique_srp_id;
}

sub uniq {
    my %seen;
    grep !$seen{$_}++, @_;
}
```

Can anyone suggest me what wrong i am doing here.

Comment: Consider passing references (for arrays/hashes) instead of flat lists

Comment: @zdim, hmm... Taking an arbitrary number of scalars is far more useful for `uniq`.

Comment: @ikegami As a ("far") more common use case (a handful of scalars to clean up)? Right, good point.  I just get all itchy when I see multi-valued variables passed around subs freely, for fear of stack abuse or unintended flattening (and out of habits from elsewhere I guess).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are passing an array reference containing the values to the function, but the function is expecting the values directly in `@_`.

```
my @unique = uniq(@{$hash->{$id}{str}{TOKEN}});
```

On Perl 5.24+, you can use postderef to make this look a bit nicer (maybe?)

```
my @unique = uniq($hash->{$id}{str}{TOKEN}->@*)
```

On Perl 5.26+, the core version of List::Util is new enough (1.45) to contain the `uniq` function and it will be faster than your pure-perl version and also handle `undef` values distinctly.

Answer (score 2):

`uniq` expects a list but `$hash->{$id}->{str}->{TOKEN}` is an array reference (a single element). Either pass an array to `uniq`

```
 uniq(@{$hash->{$id}{str}{TOKEN}})
```

or write `uniq` to expect an array reference

```
sub uniq {
    my %seen;
    grep !$seen{$_}++, @{$_[0]};
}
```